# What framework (if any) must be chosen when deploying Vite React app on Cloudflare pages?

Tags: reactjs, vite, cloudflare, cloudflare-pages

When deploying on Cloudflare pages it asks to select a framework during the process. I supposed that it will be Vite there since Create react app is present there but apparently it is not how it works. So the question is what should I choose? (During the creation of vite project React was chosen as a framework? [image: screenshot]

I suppose that it must be either "None" or "Create react app". Couldn't find any information on that online. Could you clarify that to me?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.